# Techum Shabbos in a large private area?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, real-estate, techum

The specific question came up in the context of the Disney Marathon, which is actually on Sunday, and the previous day on Shabbos is a half marathon.  (They have a combo award for those who do both).  Agreed, one should not do the half marathon on Shabbos.  However, the question I came up with, since the race is done mostly on roads between the various theme parks, where no one really lives, so on top of everything else, it seems likely that the Techum issue would be there.

But the land is all owned by Disney, and fenced, and protected.  How does Techum work in such a case?  You have a LARGE plot of land, large enough to contain a city, then a migrash then a techum, and still be entirely on private property.

Does Techum still apply if it is all on private land?  Especially if fenced in completely (Which I do not know to be true of Disney, but assume it likely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that Disney-land is הוקף לדירה as it's for visiting and not for living in.

As a result, the Halacha in the Rambam הלכות עירובין פרק ז siman 4 which seems to imply that a very large area not הוקף לדירה has a Techum Shabbos issue.

> מי שעמד מבעוד יום ברשות היחיד, וקנה שם שביתה, או שהיה בא בדרך ונתכוון לשבות ברשות היחיד הידועה אצלו, וקבע שם שביתתו--הרי זה מהלך את כולה, וחוצה לה אלפיים אמה לכל רוח.  ואם הייתה רשות היחיד זו **מקום שלא הוקף לדירה**, או תל, או נקע--אם היה בה בית סאתיים או פחות, מהלך את כולה, וחוצה לה אלפיים אמה לכל רוח; **ואם הייתה יתר על בית סאתיים, אין לו בה אלא ארבע אמות**, **וחוצה מהן אלפיים אמה לכל רוח**.  וכן אם הניח עירובו, במקום שלא הוקף לדירה.

As you can see from the ending - even putting an Eruv-Techumim there would not help.